# I want to make MongoEngine Query that just return the vehicle that i want, but it doesnt work

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, fastapi

I'm using MongoEngine to create a query that return just vehicles that match with the constraint. As can you see Vehicle is an EmbeddedDocument and Owner is the parent document. My query is using Q, the result of the query is different that just vehicles matched with Honda brand and Element model.

```
from mongoengine.queryset.visitor import Q

def get_vehicles():
    vehicles = json.loads(Owner.objects(Q(vehicle__brand='Honda') and Q(vehicle__model='Element')).only('vehicle').to_json())
    return {"vehicles":vehicles} 

class Vehicle(engine.EmbeddedDocument):
    model = engine.StringField(required=True, max_length=50)
    brand = engine.StringField(required=True, max_length=100)
    plates = engine.StringField(required=True, max_length=50)
    year =  engine.IntField(required=True)
    color = engine.StringField(required=True, max_length=80)
    type = engine.StringField(required=True, max_length=80)
    subtype = engine.StringField(required=True, max_length=80)
    doors = engine.IntField(required=True)
    transmission = engine.StringField(required=True, max_length=80)
    photos = engine.ListField(engine.StringField(max_length=150))
    equipment = engine.ListField(engine.StringField(max_length=80))
    powered_by = engine.StringField(required=True, max_length=80)
    availability = engine.ListField(engine.DateField())
    pickup_place = engine.PointField()
    creation_date = engine.DateTimeField(required=True)

class Owner(engine.Document):
    _id = engine.ObjectIdField()
    name = engine.StringField(required=True, max_length=100)
    surname = engine.StringField(required=True, max_length=100)
    gender = engine.StringField(required=True, max_length=1)
    birthday = engine.DateField(required=True)
    creation_date = engine.DateTimeField(required=True)
    last_update = engine.DateTimeField()
    photo = engine.StringField(required=True, max_length=200)
    access = engine.EmbeddedDocumentField(Access)
    address = engine.EmbeddedDocumentField(Address)
    vehicle = engine.EmbeddedDocumentListField(Vehicle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you are querying the parent collection (Owner) so the query returns all owner document with any of the Vehicle matching your Q conditions.

Although not elegant, adding a second filtering pass in Python will do the trick:

```
from mongoengine import *
connect()


class Vehicle(EmbeddedDocument):
    model = StringField(required=True, max_length=50)
    brand = StringField(required=True, max_length=100)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Vehicle({self.brand} - {self.model})'

class Owner(Document):
    vehicles = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Vehicle)
    
Owner(vehicles=[Vehicle(model="Civic", brand="Honda"), Vehicle(model="Element", brand="Honda")]).save()
Owner(vehicles=[Vehicle(model="Golf", brand="VW")]).save()

def get_vehicles(brand, model):
    matched_owners = Owner.objects(Q(vehicles__brand=brand) and Q(vehicles__model=model)).only('vehicles')
    vehicles = [vehicle for owner in matched_owners for vehicle in owner.vehicles if vehicle.brand == brand and vehicle.model == model]
    return vehicles


get_vehicles("Honda", "Element") # Print [Vehicle(Honda - Element)]
```

What you want is probably feasible using an aggregation pipeline but if your use case is really this one, you'll be just fine with this

Off topic but I'd recommend you to avoid defining a '_id' attribute, MongoEngine gives you a `id = ObjectIdField()` field by default and uses "_id" attribute internally so it's not a good idea to overwrite it (main MongoEngine contributor here)

Comment: thanks for your answer,  i attempted but  this line throws an error 

matched_owners = Owner.objects(Q(vehicle__brand='Honda') and Q(vehicle__model='Element')).only('vehicle')

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison, it works when

json.loads(Owner.objects(Q(vehicle__brand='Honda') and Q(vehicle__model='Element')).only('vehicle').to_json())

i don't know if it is a bug

Comment: The snippet I posted here works, what I'd suggest is that you start from there and gradually add your logic to it until you see it breaking. Once you know what causes it to break, open another question or if you think it's a bug, open a ticket in the github repo. Please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful

Comment: i get the result that i want, but on Mongo shell, using aggregation pipeline, but using aggregation on Mongoengine doesn't work.

This is my query on MongoShell:

`db.owner.aggregate([{ $unwind:"$vehicle"}, {$match:{ "vehicle.model":"Jetta", "vehicle.brand":"VW"}}, {$project: {"vehicle.model":1, "vehicle.brand":1, "vehicle.color":1, "vehicle.doors":1, "vehicle.transmission":1, "vehicle.powered_by":1 ,"vehicle.photos":1, "vehicle.equipment":1, "vehicle.availability":1, "vehicle.pickup_place":1}} ]);`

Answer (score 0):

i'm near to the result that i want, but i need to add the result the  owner id to vehicle.

```py
def get_vehicles():
    matched_owners = json.loads(Owner.objects(Q(vehicle__brand='VW') and Q(vehicle__model='Jetta')).only('vehicle').to_json())
    vehicles = [ vehicle for owner in matched_owners for vehicle in owner['vehicle'] if vehicle['brand'] == "VW" and vehicle['model'] == "Jetta"]
    return {"vehicles":vehicles}
```

The query on Mongo shell that match with the result that i want is:

```py
db.owner.find({"vehicle.brand":"VW"},{vehicle:{$elemMatch:{model:"Jetta"}}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the result that i want on MongoShell

````py
db.owner.aggregate([{ $unwind:"$vehicle"}, {$match:{ "vehicle.model":"Jetta", "vehicle.brand":"VW"}}, {$project: {"vehicle.model":1, "vehicle.brand":1, "vehicle.color":1, "vehicle.doors":1, "vehicle.transmission":1, "vehicle.powered_by":1 ,"vehicle.photos":1, "vehicle.equipment":1, "vehicle.availability":1, "vehicle.pickup_place":1}} ]);```  


i attempted to do the same on MongoEngine, but the result is different:

```python
def get_vehicles():
    pipeline = [
        
            { "$unwind":"$vehicle"},
            {
                "$match":{ "vehicle.model":"Jetta", "vehicle.brand":"VW"}
            },
            {
                "$project": {"vehicle.model":1, "vehicle.brand":1, "vehicle.color":1, "vehicle.doors":1, "vehicle.transmission":1, "vehicle.powered_by":1 ,"vehicle.photos":1, "vehicle.equipment":1, "vehicle.availability":1, "vehicle.pickup_place":1}
            }
        ]
    vehicles = Owner.objects.aggregate(pipeline)
    return {"vehicles":vehicles}```
````